# Standalone utility to capture stderr and stdout like in Eclipse?

Tags: debugging, stdout, capture, stderr, utility

Please suggest standalone utility for windows which allows start application and capture it's stdout and strerr (with different colors) which is similar to Eclipse debugger console window.

Something like improvement to windows' `start` command, but not so clumsy (i.e. with ability to lock scrolling and copy easily to clipboard).